# How to get the UID's of all contactless smartcards in the field of a reader using Java?

Tags: java, smartcard, acr122

I have an ACR122U reader. I want to be able to get the UID's of all contactless smartcards that are placed on top of the reader. Similar to what the `nfc-list` command from libnfc does.

I'm using SmartCardIO at the moment, but it doesn't seem to have the capability to do this. I have searched around and I haven't been able to find anything that can do this. Does anybody know of anything that can? Or how I would go about implementing it?

I basically need to be able to handle multiple cards in the card readers field, and process them one by one with SmartCardIO.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with any standard Java SE runtime to my knowledge. You will need to create a library that performs this yourself. For this you'll need the C/C++ API of the reader and use JNI (or one of the easier to use derivatives). UID's are at a lower protocol level than smartcardio operates on.